# Avoid instantiate class X times when adding to List<>?

Tags: c#, oop

I have `class StatsFile` that looks like the following. It has two fields that save two strings that will be added to a `List<>`:

```
public class StatsFile
{
    public string RemoteFileName;
    public string LocalFileName;
}
```

Then I have another `class FileProcessor` with `method GetAllFiles` that fills a `List<>` with several `StatsFile`s:

```
class FileProcessor
{
    public List<StatsFile> GetAllFiles()
    {
        List<StatsFile> fileList = new List<StatsFile>();

        StatsFile weekFiles = new StatsFile();

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file1";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file1";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file2";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file2";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file3";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file3";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        return fileList;
    }           
}
```

Being just one instance of `StatsFile`, then all items in `List<>` will have the same values. I can instantiate `StatsFile` 3 times which would resolve the issue, but is there another way of reusing that same instance? Or maybe a better way?

Comment: Probably a copying mistake / tyop(s), but didn't you mean `weekFiles.RemoteFileName = ...`?

Comment: What do you want to gain here?

Comment: If you want three distinct objects, you're going to have to create three `new` objects.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But if the OP made `StatsFile` a value type, as suggested in my answer (and yantaq's answer), then the objects won't need to be "distinct", since value types don't have identity.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I guess I was being loose with my use of "object."  I meant reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **struct** instead of class for `StatsFile` type.

```
public struct StatsFile
{
    public string RemoteFileName { get; set; }
    public string LocalFileName { get; set; }
}

class FileProcessor
{
    public List<StatsFile> GetAllFiles()
    {
        var fileList = new List<StatsFile>();
        StatsFile weekFiles;

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = @"Remote\file1";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = @"Local\file1";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = @"Remote\file2";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = @"Local\file2";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        weekFiles.RemoteFileName = @"Remote\file3";
        weekFiles.LocalFileName = @"Local\file3";
        fileList.Add(weekFiles);

        return fileList;
    }           
}
```

**Here is the result**

```
FileProcessor fp = new FileProcessor();
var result = fp.GetAllFiles();
result.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to assign a `new StatsFile();` to the struct.

Comment: @Amit, noted the comment thanks. sometimes it's hard to remember those when switching languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize the variables during construction:

```
class FileProcessor
{
    public List<StatsFile> GetAllFiles()
    {
        List<StatsFile> fileList = new List<StatsFile>();

        fileList.Add(new StatsFile {
            RemoteFileName = "Remote\file1",
            LocalFileName = "Local\file1"
        });

        fileList.Add(new StatsFile {
            RemoteFileName = "Remote\file2",
            LocalFileName = "Local\file2"
        });

        fileList.Add(new StatsFile {
            RemoteFileName = "Remote\file3",
            LocalFileName = "Local\file3"
        });

        return fileList;
    }           
}
```

Comment: That would still be creating 3 instances. In the OP's case, a value type seems more appropriate, anyway.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Quote from OP: "*Or maybe a better way?*". I think that's better. Regarding using a value type, maybe... depends on usage throughout the code. And I'm not saying it's less appropriate, I'm saying both are.

Comment: This is a clean way of writing the code and is probably the best option in this case.  There's generally no reason to be afraid of creating new objects; memory allocation in .NET is actually quite fast.  Creating a mutable value type to avoid calling 'new' is a terrible idea.

Comment: @DanBryant I agree that creating a mutable value type _just_ to avoid creating instances is a bad idea, but in this case, looking at the problem domain, it does seem a value type is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the answers given here, you can also add a method to your `StatsFile` class and call it `AddCurrentInstance`. This method can receive a `List<StatsFile>` as input and add self's clone to it.

So, `StatsFile` will have the following method:

```
public void AddCurrentInstance (List<StatsFile> listings)
{
    if (listings == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received null listings. Returning...");
        return;
    }
    listings.Add(this.clone());
}
```

And now, your calls will become something like the following:

```
public List<StatsFile> GetAllFiles()
{
    List<StatsFile> fileList = new List<StatsFile>();
    StatsFile weekFiles = new StatsFile();

    weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file1";
    weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file1";
    weekFiles.AddCurrentInstance(fileList);

    weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file2";
    weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file2";
    weekFiles.AddCurrentInstance(fileList);

    weekFiles.RemoteFileName = "Remote\file3";
    weekFiles.LocalFileName = "Local\file3";
    weekFiles.AddCurrentInstance(fileList);

    return fileList;
}
```